# How to find out which Approval Step has just been completed

Tags: apex, approval-process, casemilestone

In certain situations, I may have several approval steps for a **Case** which will be approved by several different users.

I need my Apex trigger to complete a **CaseMilestone**, if a particular step has been approved. I'm looking for the best way to check that the correct step has just been approved.

I've found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008mUVIAY/) post in the Developer Forum which suggests a field update to a field which would contain the number of the approval step that's just been completed. But this would potentially require a lot of maintenance.

I could also create a field update, as an Approval Action, to tick a tickbox on the Case when a particular step is completed and check whether the tickbox is TRUE/FALSE in the trigger. But again this seems inflexible and if the same tickbox ends up being updated by multiple approval processes, there's the risk of confusion.

Do I have any other alternatives?

Comment: just curious...let us say a Case record C is undergoing an Approval Process A1..what is the use case in which the same case record C will also undergo another approval process (let us say A2..) while being processed in A1 ..Is it even possible ?..I could be wrong..just asking

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible but I wouldn't even want to use the same tick box on a separate Case with a different approval process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a picklist with different milestones?

For example:
Stage__c

```
  Open
  First Step
  Second Step
  Third Step
  Closed
```

And in your approval process, when you've reached a certain point you can field update this picklist to step it's currently on?